# SOLR and complex pricing

Tags: solr

We have a property booking site (similar to Airbnb) with a LAMP setup and a relatively simple SOLR index. A user can search by:

- Location
- Guests
- Date IN/OUT

They can also filter results for a specific price range, as well as sort by price.

The issue is that price per night is never fixed, and is depends on several things such as custom prices (for one day, or a range of days), price per guest, discounts (e.g. weekend discount) etc. One example could be that price_per_night might be 50$, however for the 10th and 11th of August the real price per night could be 110$ plus 20$ extra guest fee, minus a discount of 30$ for that particular weekend. On top of this, commissions are applied on the total amount so we'd like this to be as accurate as possible.

While we can calculate this on the server side, this of course affects the results returned for a price range as well as the sorting (highest price first vs. lowest).

Could anyone suggest any possible solution?

Below is an example of a select:

```
"docs": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "property_type": 1,
    "room_type": 1,
    "minimum_nights": 2,
    "maximum_nights": 120,
    "location": "41.3902359,2.1685901",
    "price_per_night": 210,
    ........
    "unavailable_days": [
      "2016-09-15T00:00:00Z",
      "2016-09-16T00:00:00Z",
      ......
    ]
}
```